CA Code G2 Initial Value vs G2 Delay
In IS-GPS-200N, table  6-I beginning on page 55 lists the G2 delay and G2 initial values needed to generate PRN sequences for SVNs larger than 63. One of the WAAS satellites is PRN 135, so I used the table to generate the CA code for it with both Verilog and C. My goal was to find the G2 initial value for any PRN using the delay value as a seed. The purpose was to verify the given G2 initial value from the table matched what was generated using the G2 delay method. I thought that all I had to do was delay the G2 start by the number of clocks given by the delay value, then take whatever G2 value was present when G1 rolled over to the all 1s epoch. So long as my first 10 CA values matched the table, I should be golden. What I found was way more confounding than that. I got the first ten values to match, but they were the inverse of each other. Meaning, they were binary mirror images. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't they produce the same code?
Perhaps the following output helps illustrate my question:
$ tail -15 prn135_G2Init.txt
G1 = 0x3FC 0 G2 = 0x239 1 bit = 0, 0 1022
G1 = 0x3FE 0 G2 = 0x11C 0 bit = 1, 1 0
G1 = 0x3FF 1 G2 = 0x28E 0 bit = 0, 0 1
G1 = 0x1FF 1 G2 = 0x347 1 bit = 0, 0 2
G1 = 0x0FF 1 G2 = 0x1A3 1 bit = 0, 0 3
G1 = 0x07F 1 G2 = 0x0D1 1 bit = 1, 1 4
G1 = 0x23F 1 G2 = 0x268 0 bit = 1, 1 5
G1 = 0x31F 1 G2 = 0x134 0 bit = 1, 1 6
G1 = 0x38F 1 G2 = 0x29A 0 bit = 0, 0 7
G1 = 0x1C7 1 G2 = 0x34D 1 bit = 1, 1 8
G1 = 0x0E3 1 G2 = 0x3A6 0 bit = 0, 0 9
G1 = 0x071 1 G2 = 0x1D3 1
First 10 CA bits: 0101110001 = o561
First 10 CA bits reversed: 1000111010 = o1072
    
$ tail -15 prn135_G2Delay.txt
G1 = 0x3FC 0 G2 = 0x317 1 bit = 1, 1 1022
G1 = 0x3FE 0 G2 = 0x38B 1 bit = 0, 0 0
G1 = 0x3FF 1 G2 = 0x1C5 1 bit = 1, 1 1
G1 = 0x1FF 1 G2 = 0x0E2 0 bit = 0, 0 2
G1 = 0x0FF 1 G2 = 0x071 1 bit = 1, 1 3
G1 = 0x07F 1 G2 = 0x038 0 bit = 1, 1 4
G1 = 0x23F 1 G2 = 0x21C 0 bit = 1, 1 5
G1 = 0x31F 1 G2 = 0x10E 0 bit = 0, 0 6
G1 = 0x38F 1 G2 = 0x287 1 bit = 0, 0 7
G1 = 0x1C7 1 G2 = 0x143 1 bit = 0, 0 8
G1 = 0x0E3 1 G2 = 0x2A1 1 bit = 1, 1 9
G1 = 0x071 1 G2 = 0x150 0
First 10 CA bits: 1000111010 = o1072
First 10 CA bits reversed: 0101110001 = o561

Two different implementations using the same basic structure produced similar but inverse codes. The code produced with a G2 Initialization value does not look like the delay-based method backward. They appear to be two different codes. The G2Init version clearly shows the init value from table 6-I, o1216 = 0x28E, so that approach did produce a periodic code. The delay method also repeats but does not produce the same G2 initial value. How would I get the delay-based method to produce a non-inverted version of the G2 Initialization method? (one that's not inverted?)
I appreciate the answer using variable G2 taps, but my question is not about that approach. As stated in the first sentence, this question is about PRNs greater than 63 where changing which two taps are fed back will not work. The question concerns getting the G2 delay and G2 Init methods to produce corroborating outcomes. I wanted to find the G2 init value from the delay because the smaller PRNs don't give a G2 init value. One way to obtain the G2 initialization value is supposed to be to invert the First ten CA bits. So, that is a potential approach to obtain the G2 init value for the PRNs below 63 where only the dealy and first 10 CA bits are given in the table, but when I tried that approach, it did not work. What is the correct approach to determine the G2 initialization value for any PRN given the data provided in IS-GPS-200?

I found what I was looking for. I'll try to explain it. The correct G2 initialization value is not the "inverse" of the First 10 CA Chips, at least according to any definition of "inverse" I could find. I don't know what you would call it, but "reverse" is more appropriate than inverse, and even that isn't the best term because it's a bit flipped reverse. Maybe obverse? Anyway, I would almost go so far as to say the values published in the IS-GPS-200 document are misleading at best. I can get the G2 initialization method to match the G2 delay method by taking the provided First 10 Chips, reversing them, and flipping their bit values. Take PRN 135 as an example:
1) Get First 10 Chips from Table 6-I: 10'o0561 = 10'b0101110001
2) Invert the bits from the F10Chips: 10'o1216 = 10'b1010001110
3) Reverse the order for the G2 Init: 10'o0705 = 10'b0111000101

Notice that the table shows o1216 as the G2 initial setting. That's what produced the backward code that doesn't work. The third step is the critical piece that makes the two code-generation methods match one another. Now they both work.

Below shows the C/A code generator I use with the implementation straight out of the signal definition specification (and the MATLAB code for the generator I did using this is available here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14670-gps-c-a-code-generator
(I also have this available in Python upon request)
The block diagram is shown below:

This is a "Gold Code" Generator which brings up a lot of interesting properties of Maximum Length Psuedo-Random Number (PRN) generators as follows: the G1 and G2 polynomials each describe a different 10th order Maximum Length Sequence, whose implementation with simple shift registers (and XOR gates as the 2-element Galois Field adders) as shown in the diagram above as Linear Feedback Shift Registers (LFSR). They are "Maximum Length" as the state of the registers will step through every possible combination once (except the all-zero state) before repeating.
There are two common ways of implementing such pseudo-random noise (PRN) sequences: the Fibonacci as shown and the Galois which is really just reversing the signal flow diagram (reverse all directions, change summers to branches and change branches to adders). The two forms are shown below:

The issue is that there aren't a lot of 10th order polynomials (see the famous Peterson's Table of Irreducible Polynomials over GF(2)) which conveniently catalog's them all for us. As the document describes, out of the polynomial's listed, only the ones with an E, F, G, or H are primitive. Assuming I counted correctly, there are only 30 10th order polynomials listed. The reciprocal of these polynomials (reverse order) is also primitive resulting in 60 total choices (which includes the G1 and G2 polynomials for the GPS C/A Gold Code generator).
This leads to the cool property leading to Gold Codes. If we sum two M-sequence LFSR outputs together (sum in GF(2) which means XOR), the result will be another PRN sequence and since each of the two (G1 and G2 outputs) repeat after every $2^{10}-1$ cycles, the output of this summation must also repeat as such. However if we were to delay the output of G1 or G2 before summing, the resulting output would be a completely different PRN sequence. Since we can have up to $2^{10}-1$ unique shifts, the result will provide $2^{10}-1$ possible unique codes, each $2^{10}-1$ long! Further these codes all have good cross correlation properties (not as good as pure Maximum length sequences, but nearly so!) such that they can be considered uncorrelated to each other. So instead of having just 60 code choices, we have 1023 code choices with the Gold code.
The other interesting property that we see in this Gold Code implementation is if you were to take one Maximum Length Sequence (here G2) and add it (in GF(2)) to a delayed copy of itself, the result will be the same sequence at a completely different delayed location. Thus the taps selected provide different combinations of delayed copies of the same sequence to generate the 32 different delayed results of G2 as listed in the table.
Further, if you were to convolve the two polynomials (which is polynomial multiplication) over GF(2) (which can be done by replacing all even number results with 0 and all odd number results with 1), the result is a 20th order polynomial. Thus you can implement all the GPS C/A codes with a single 20th order LFSR using the convolution of the G1 and G2 polynomials. This is not an irreducible polynomial (obviously since we can factor it or reduce it back to G1 and G2), so it will generate the same as the sum of it's reduced factors (the Gold Code) and which code out of the 1023 choices depending on its initial state! As part of the team developing the GPS M-code, I had conceived of an had the opportunity to implement a "universal PRN generator" using such a 20th order single LFSR, and then determined the seeds for any particular sequence needed including all of the C/A codes (the seeds are easily extracted from the GPS signal: take any successive 20 chips for a particular PRN ID and use that as the state of the 20th order LFSR and it will continue and generate the 1023 length code for that PRN ID. This approach resulted in a sequence generator with much more flexibility than the specific architecture shown in the block diagram above, which was ideal for the research needs at the time.

Thank you for taking the time to post an answer. I need some help connecting the dots between the question and this answer. The Matlab code appears to address Table 3-Ia on pages 6 and 7 of IS-GPS-200N. It does not address Table 3-Ib on page 8 nor Table 6-I on pages 55-59 as cited in the original post. I could see how one could answer the question with information contained in this post, but the path to that answer is not clear to me.

@KyleG Ah I see—- sorry I read your question too quickly; I’ll see if I can add that detail. Any chance you can add a similar block diagram as to how you actually implemented your generator?

It should be that you start both g1 and g2 in the all 1 state and then delay g2 by the delay indicated before combining with the GF(2) adder. Is that indeed what you did?

Yes I did. I'll provide more information. Turns out that the octal inverse of the First Ten CA Bits doesn't produce the desired result. I'll edit my post. I can correlate satellite signals with the delay-based generator, but the G2 init version doesn't work. Likely because it's backward. That's what I'm trying to sort out. The real question is, how do you determine what the G2 init value needs to be for any PRN?

I have a Python script and generate the state by advancing the generator that many chips. It’s quick to make the table which I can use later. However I suggest posting that very question much more conscisely as a separate post- Professor Dillip Sawarte who frequents here is an expert in the number theory involved so may know of a direct approach (I do not). Keep it very short and easy to read and you’ll get more attention
